# ASP.NET C# SEO for each product on detail page on my ECOMMERCE site

Tags: c#, asp.net, seo, meta-tags

I have been working on an ECOMMERCE site in ASP.NET C# for about a month and completed the site successfully. After the development I am having some issues in the SEO of my site. Let me explain;

I have a master page that has the top menu and a child page that contains the product details. Product details are passed to the child page through query string containing ID of the product and fetch the data of that particular product. I have 10,000 products in my database so how to do SEO for each product when I have only 1 page like for each and every item I want to do SEO.

Reason for asking this question is that I want to know the best approach, using SITEMAP with the URL routes, titles, description or implementing dynamic META tags in my child page whenever it is redirected with the product ID.

I am kinda confused. Please help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if this is possible in your case but one of the things i have on a similar site which is helpfull for SEO is I added a product url field to my product table for a nice url. I make sure to only allow unique urls for each product.  So for example here is a link to one of the products www.example.com/Dell-Compatible-Memory-for-Poweredge-R720-and-R620-Server-64GB-Kit

I have the product name in the url. I just use the product url to look up my product instead of using an ID. Also i dont know if you are using mvc 5 which supports attribute routing. That way i inlcude optional parameters in my url and dont have to use the query string. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

The othe thing you can do in MVC in is use a section to insert your meta tag into the layout head:

```
     <head>

         @RenderSection("AdditionalMeta", false)

     </head>
```

and in your view:

```
 @section AdditionalMeta
 {
      <meta name="@ProductName" content="@Description">
 }
```

If you are using webforma you can see how to handle your meta taga here  https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2006/Aug/04/No-more-Meta-Refresh-Tags

Comment: Thanks a lot dude :)